# Pull from multiple SCM then mv file in Concourse CI to workdir

Tags: continuous-integration, yaml, pipeline, mv, concourse

I've been banging my head on this one for quite some time and I cannot figure it out (I know it must be a simple thing to do though).

Currently, what I'm trying to do is pulling from two repositories (which naturally creates two separate directories) then I'm trying to move files from one directory to the other to successfully execute the Dockerfile.

Here's how my pipeline.yml file looks like:

```
---
jobs:
- name: build-nexus-docker-image
  public: false
  plan:
  - get: git-nexus-docker-images
    trigger: true
  - get: git-nexus-license
    trigger: true
  - task: mv-nexus-license
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: ubuntu, tag: "trusty"}
      inputs:
        - name: git-nexus-license
        - name: git-nexus-docker-images
      run:
        path: /bin/sh
        args:
          - -c
          - mv -v git-nexus-license/nexus.lic git-nexus-docker-images/nexus.lic; ls -la git-nexus-docker-images
  - put: nexus-docker-image
    params:
      build: git-nexus-docker-images/

resources:
- name: git-nexus-docker-images
  type: git
  source:
    uri: git@git.company.com:dev/nexus-pro-dockerfile.git
    branch: test
    paths: [Dockerfile]
    private_key: {{git_ci_key}}

- name: git-nexus-license
  type: git
  source:
    uri: git@git.company.com:secrets/nexus-information.git
    branch: master
    paths: [nexus.lic]
    private_key: {{git_ci_key}}

- name: nexus-docker-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
    username: {{aws-token-username}}
    password: {{aws-token-password}}
    repository: {{ecr-nexus-repo}}
```

I've posted the pipeline that actually can be deployed to Concourse; however I tried a lot of things, but I can't figure out how to do this. I'm stuck on the part of moving the license file from `git-nexus-license` directory to `git-nexus-docker-images` directory. What I've done doesn't seem to mv the `nexus.lic` file because when while building the docker image it fails because it cannot find that file in the directory.

EDIT: I've successfully been able to "mv" `nexus.lic` using the code above, however the build is still failing due to not finding the file! I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, the build works properly if I do it manually but with Concourse it's failing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay so I figured out what I was doing wrong and as usual it was something small. I forgot to add the `outputs` to the yml file which tells concourse that this is the new workdir. Here's how it looks like now (which works for me):

```
---
jobs:
- name: build-nexus-docker-image
  public: false
  plan:
  - get: git-nexus-docker-images
    trigger: true
  - get: git-nexus-license
    trigger: true
  - task: mv-nexus-license
    config:
      platform: linux
      image_resource:
        type: docker-image
        source: {repository: ubuntu, tag: "trusty"}
      inputs:
        - name: git-nexus-license
        - name: git-nexus-docker-images
      outputs:
        - name: build-nexus-dir
      run:
        path: /bin/sh
        args:
          - -c
          - mv -v git-nexus-license/nexus.lic build-nexus-dir/nexus.lic; mv -v git-nexus-docker-images/* build-nexus-dir; ls -la build-nexus-dir;
  - put: nexus-docker-image
    params:
      build: build-nexus-dir/

resources:
- name: git-nexus-docker-images
  type: git
  source:
    uri: git@git.company.com:dev/nexus-pro-dockerfile.git
    branch: test
    paths: [Dockerfile]
    private_key: {{git_ci_key}}

- name: git-nexus-license
  type: git
  source:
    uri: git@git.company.com:secrets/nexus-information.git
    branch: master
    paths: [nexus.lic]
    private_key: {{git_ci_key}}

- name: nexus-docker-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
    username: {{aws-token-username}}
    password: {{aws-token-password}}
    repository: {{ecr-nexus-repo}}
```

I hope this helps whoever gets stuck on this. :)